# Heroku. New Relic Procfile command doesn't work

Tags: python, django, heroku, newrelic

I've been trying to add New Relic to my app but I get this error:

```
at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed"
```

The error comes from the Procfile line where I declare the web process. I followed the documentations which states [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/newrelic#python-installation-and-configuration) and [here](https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/agents/python-agent/getting-started/django-heroku-quick-start) that the proccess should be declared like this:

```
web: newrelic-admin run-program python manage.py run_gunicorn -b "0.0.0.0:$PORT" -w 3
```

It doesn't work.

How should I declare the web process in the Procfile for New Relic to work?

I'm using Django.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok. I found that if I declare the web process like this, it works:

```
web: newrelic-admin run-program gunicorn appname.wsgi
```

I will not mark this question as the accepted answer cause in the docs, [here](https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/agents/python-agent/hosting-services/python-agent-heroku), it writes that that line is for "Flask with the built-in development server". Therefore this is a temporary solution, anyway, maybe it helps someone.